# How to get attributes from table that joins of HABTM

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I models are

```rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :recipients
  has_many :notifications, through: :recipients
end

class Recipient < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :notification
end

class Notification < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :recipients

  scope :unread, -> { ??? }

  def read?
    # ???
  end
end
```

I've page with list of notifications, that are received using: `@user.notifications`. But I need to detect which notifications aren't read yet. For this I have join table `recipients` which has field `read_at`.

### Question

I want to get unread notifications like that

```rb
user.notifications.unread
```

and check that specified notification isn't read

```rb
user.notifications.each { |n| n.read? }
```

In first case I want to get query

```
SELECT "notifications".*
FROM "notifications"
  INNER JOIN "recipients" ON "notifications"."id" = "recipients"."notification_id"
WHERE "recipients"."user_id" = $1
  AND "recipients"."read_at" IS NOT NULL
```

In the second, I would like to avoid additional queries.

Is it possible?

Comment: get unread notification - `user.notifications.where(recipients: { read_at: nil })`.

Comment: also, you might want to add rather add scope in `User`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add scope in `User` rather than `Notification`, because your beginning point is `user` rather than notifications.

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :recipients
  has_many :notifications, through: :recipients

  def unread_notifications 
    notifications.where(recipients: { read_at: nil })
  end

  def read_notifications 
    notifications.where.not(recipients: { read: nil })
  end
end

user.notifications #=> all notifications
user.unread_notifications #=> all unread notifications of user
user.read_notifications #=> all read notifications of user
```

To determine if a notification is read by all:

```
class Notification < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :recipients

  def read?
    recipients.all?(&:read_at)
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you! What about checking of specified notification?

Comment: added in answer. try to understand the logic of why it's written that way

Comment: It works if `unread_notifications` is method, instead of scope in model `User`, but `User.find(1).unread_notifications.map { |n| n.read? }`doesn't works (
It says that `wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0)` for method `all?`

Comment: edited the answer. missed `&`. It should have been `recipients.all?(&:read_at)`

Comment: I've found. You need to fix braces  `recipients.all? {:read_at}`
https://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/all%3F

Comment: no. you can get away from braces with the shorthand syntax in the answer. `recipients.all?(&:read_at)` is same as `recipients.all?{ |r| r.read_at }`

Comment: I understand how it works! Thank you. It generates many queries, but it works)
I can accept your answer if you will change scope to methods `def unread_notifications 
    notifications.where(recipients: { read_at: nil })
  end`

Comment: changed to method. my bad in that. having scope gives the ability on `User` model rather than `user` object. edited the answer.

Comment: I can't raise the raiting of your answer (I've little reputation), but accepted it. Thank you again)

Comment: Not an issue at all. Glad it solved your problem. Have fun with Ruby and Rails! It's truly magical :D

Comment: Method `read?` doesn't works correctly. It detects all 'recipients' that are related to the specified notification. If one of them isn't `read` yet then the method says `false` always.
I'm sorry =)

Comment: My solution is: 
```def read_by?(user)
    Recipient.where(notification: self, user: user).where.not(read_at: nil).count > 0
  end```